# How to install Relayer for Cosmos SDK Starport chain

Tags: go, blockchain, cosmos-sdk

I have created a blockchain with Starport (https://github.com/tendermint/starport).

The command to install I used was `starport app github.com/tosch110/stargateapp --sdk-version=stargate`

Now trying to run `starport serve` and start my blockchain, I get

```
Cosmos' version is: Stargate
Error: Please, check that Relayer is installed.
Usage:
  starport serve [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help          help for serve
  -p, --path string   path of the app
  -v, --verbose       Verbose output

Please, check that Relayer is installed.
```

How do I install Relayer? Is there a particular repository / documentation which needs to be installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relayer is an off-chain program that has a wallet with tokens, watches one or more blockchains for interchain transactions, and sends them to corresponding blockchains.

There is [an implementation of a relayer](https://github.com/cosmos/relayer) in Go. To install it, run the following commands:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/cosmos/relayer

cd relayer

make install
```

This will install a `rly` binary. [Starport](https://github.com/tendermint/starport) will automatically use `rly` to set up relayer configuration between chains.